# Нужна ли запятая перед словом "какое"?

Tags: запятые

*Промышленный доильный аппарат и бытовой различаются тем(,) какое количество голов система может обслуживать одновременно.*

Нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, *запятая нужна.* Она отделяет придаточное предложение от главного.

Comment: Так переставить нельзя. Можно так: "промышленный и бытовой доильные аппараты различаются...". Попробуйте, для примера, сказать "зелёный воздушный и синий шарик отличаются цветом".

Comment: Точно, спасибо. У вас, кстати, точка лишняя в конце первой строчки.